# Generic method call for related methods

Tags: c#, generic-collections

How can I make this code better? It would be better if I could modify method GetItemsInfo() to send several types at one call.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class SomeClass
{
  List<Item> itemBase;
...
   public IEnumerable<ItemInfo>  SomeMethod()
   {
      return itemBase.GetItemsInfo<GeneralItem>()
                .Concat(itemBase.GetItemsInfo<FirstTypeItem>())
                .Concat(itemBase.GetItemsInfo<SecondTypeItem>())
                .Concat(itemBase.GetItemsInfo<ThirdTypeItem>());
   }
}
```

where

```
public class ItemInfo
{...}
public class GeneralItem :ItemInfo
{...}
public class FirstTypeItem :ItemInfo
{...}
...
```

```
List<ItemInfo> items;
...
public IEnumerable<ItemInfo> GetItemsInfo<T>() where T: ItemInfo
        {
            return items.Where(item => item.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)));
        }
```

Thanks!

Update. Question updated by concrette realization of GetItemsInfo.

One more update.
For now I wrote non-generic method

```
 public IEnumerable<ItemInfo> GetItemsInfo(params System.Type[] types) 
        {
            return items.Where(item => types.Any(type => type.Equals(item.GetType())));
        }
```

But It isn't looks pretty. Because in this array user can add any Type he wants even not child of ItemInfo. Maybe it's not a problem cause items is the collection of ItemInfo objects.

Comment: Well what is `GetItemsInfo`? Yes, you could do `GetItemsInfo<T1, T2, T3>()`.

Comment: It would help if you explain to us *what* you try to achieve instead of *how* you want to achieve it

Comment: How does your `GetItemsInfo` implementation look? Do you want it to return all subtypes of `Item`?

Comment: I have a collection of many different Item Infos. So I'm trying to get a number of item infos of certain types. And in every part of code there are different list of certain types

`public IEnumerable<ItemInfo> GetItemsInfo<T>() where T: ItemInfo
 {
return items.Where(item => item.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)));
}`

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based question. From my POV, `GetItemsInfo` would look better with `return items.OfType<T>();`. You can also pass an array of types to the method to match using a single loop instead of concatenating.

Comment: I think this question would fit better on [codereview.se] since the OP wants to improve his code.

Comment: @Amy Code Review doesn't accept hypothetical/stub code though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the [OfType method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8)? Then I would think you'd need:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemInfo>  SomeMethod()
{
    return itemBase.OfType<GeneralItem>()
        .Concat(itemBase.OfType<FirstTypeItem>())
        .Concat(itemBase.OfType<SecondTypeItem>())
        .Concat(itemBase.OfType<ThirdTypeItem>());
}
```

Means you've reinvented the wheel... And you might even shorten it to:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemInfo>  SomeMethod()
{
    return itemBase.OfType<ItemInfo>();
}
```

As all the classes you're filtering share this common ancestor.

---

For an exact match on type, you could use this extention method inside a static class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MatchType<T>(this IEnumerable<object> data)
=> data.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
```

Now you would use this code instead:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemInfo>  SomeMethod()
{
    return itemBase.MatchType<GeneralItem>()
        .Concat(itemBase.MatchType<FirstTypeItem>())
        .Concat(itemBase.MatchType<SecondTypeItem>())
        .Concat(itemBase.MatchType<ThirdTypeItem>());
}
```

Which is similar to your code, actually. A bit more generic, though. But you want a concat method that onle concats a select number of items, so you might want this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> ConcatSelect<T>(this IEnumerable<object> first, IEnumerable<object> second)
=> first.Concat(second.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(T)));
```

Again very generic so it's more reusable. This would result in this code:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemInfo>  SomeMethod()
{
    return new List<object>().
        .ConcatSelect<GeneralItem>(itemBase)
        .ConcatSelect<FirstTypeItem>(itemBase)
        .ConcatSelect<SecondTypeItem>(itemBase)
        .ConcatSelect<ThirdTypeItem>(itemBase)
        .Cast(ItemInfo);
}
```

Looks okay to me. Extremely generic, also.

Comment: Thank you and to others who tell me about **OfType**.
This classes have common parent. But I don't need all childs of **ItemInfo**. I need only _certain types_. And, as I said before, each time I suggest to use this method, there will be **different** collections of child types.

Comment: @HedgehogNSK, I've changed my answer to suggest two alternative solutions. The ConcatSelect<> method might be what you need?

Comment: not quite. I have been trying to found the solution which allows to me to pass more then 1 type as arguments to get list of ItemInfos which includes element of any of those types.

Besides, I think that SomeMethod() of yours  wouldn't work cause MatchType<T> returns IEnumerable<T> and the compiler won't let to concat IEnumerable of different types.

I'm thinking I will use this signature
`IEnumerable<ItemInfo> GetItemsInfo(params System.Type[] types) `
It's to pitty that it is without generics but it still works.

Anyway, thanks for help. You gave me helpful information to think about.

Comment: The ConcatSelect returns enumerations of objects, which are added to a List<Object>. It should be compatible. The trick is the Cast<ItemInfo> at the end, which turns the list into an IEnumerable<ItemInfo>. MatchType also does a cast back to T.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use `OfType` linq function instead of the equality check you are doing.

You can found more information [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/uses-of-oftype-in-linq).

Now for your question,
What you search is how to call a generic function with reflection.
Their are already a lot of answers for this question.

You can found a good article [here](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2019/02/calling-generic-methods-using-reflection/).